# Problem with Nautilus and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

This just happened today. Nautilus (3.8.2) on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine used to work fine, but now, when I try to run it (either from the icon or command line), it opens for about a second and then closes/crashes. The behaviour from the command line is as follows:

```
me@Bedrock1:~$ nautilus
sys:1: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(nautilus:3388): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_loader_close: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed

(nautilus:3388): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed
sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Does this make any sense? Is there an easy way to see if I installed any libraries yesterday or today, that may be causing this problem?

For now, I'm avoiding the problem by using Dolphin, but am worried there's a problem that will bite me in other applications.

Comment: Did you try to reconfigure it? `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus` Did you install any software after the last time it worked?

Comment: @the_Seppi - I just tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nautilus`, but it didn't work. I'm not certain whether I installed new libraries yesterday. I've been looking to see how I can find out. So far, the best I can do is see which packages I've installed, but not when I did it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how I fixed it, but this is what I did:

***I uninstalled & reinstalled python-nautilus & tortoisehg-nautilus*** using Synaptic. I came upon this solution as follows:

```
1 Further web-searching revealed that python-nautilus can cause the 
  Nautilus crash I saw, so I used Synaptic to uninstall it  (i.e. python-nautilus)
```

When python-nautilus was uninstalled, tortoisehg-nautilus was also uninstalled. This made nautilus work again, but .....

I had since learned how to view my installation history, and saw that the most recent installations I had before my problem were of **xsane-common**, **xsane** & **sane**. Since the two packages I unistalled had been on my system before the problem appeared, I decided to reinstall them and then see which of the sane installs caused my problem with Nautilus.

```
2 Upon reinstalling python-nautilus & tortoisehg-nautilus, Nautilus continued to work.
```

So, I don't know what originally caused my problem, nor do I understand why an uninstall/reinstall cycle should have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem with nautilus in 13.10 ; Did you have Clam antivirus installed the new version appears to scan a folder on opening causing it to crash; after reading your problem and solution I went to have a try my self with your solution using synaptic. when I went to un-install python nautilus it gave the message that clam would have to be removed, I did this with the software centre rebooted and nautilus worked no further install needed.

It could be that a recent update for ubuntu may have been the root cause, but what that is I can't say, but its left nautilus vulnerable to crashes. I will point out that I had also reloaded 13.10 yesterday and nautilus worked fine with all my programs up till today and opened folder windows with no problem until an update was downloaded.

I will say this though since I removed clam a few minutes ago and rebooted the folders are opening far quicker and so far no crash. and having just put it through its paces it seems fine at the moment, the only thing I can think of that may be a problem is the new shell integration of clam its a lot more invasive than it used to be and the new interface is I would say more than a little buggy.

Comment: Nope, I am not using Clam...